# VbScript or with Scripting

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, scripting

we need to execute scripts locally, but how can we do it from a remote machine, so as to avoid going on to each machine and triggering the process manually. preferably with VbScript.

Comment: Login Script, Group Policy or PSEXEC all come to mind.

Answer (score 0):

Generally in your VBScript you will specify the machine you want to query with the line

```
strComputer = "."
```

This can be changed to a computer name or IP address to remotely query a machine. However it is difficult to provide anything further as you've not posted your script or what you're trying to achieve with it..

Answer (score -1):

Write your .vbs scripts and deploy them to a remote server - then on the remote server schedule a task to run whenever you'd like the script to run.

The script will run locally on that server.

Comment: how can i run a script on a number of different vm's from one local machine rather than triggering it from each local machine .